# VSCode Remote Container -- how to open the default folder in the container instance of VSCode?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Whenever I attach VSCode to a container, it starts with no specific folder opened. I want to open folder "/ado" on start and apply the workspace settings there. How can I achieve this?

When I open the folder manually, I start in the /root folder of the container.

**.devcontainer.json:**

```json
{
    "name": "Portal Docker Environment",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "api",
    "workspaceFolder": "/ado",
    "cwd": "/ado",
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode"
    ]
}
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
portal:
  build: Dockerfiles/portal
  image: portal
  command: launch_portal.py
  volumes:
    - ./ado:/ado
  ports:
    - "6543"
    - "51000:51000"   # for ptvsd debugger
  env_file:
    - ./portal.env
```

I also had no luck finding the complete list of possible keywords available in .devcontainer.json. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

Update: Found the [keyword reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_devcontainerjson-reference) for .devcontainer.json

Comment: opened a ticket on Github, in case its a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/289

Answer (score 1):

Got a response in the [Github ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/289):

> "When attaching to a running container it is not known what your
>   current workspace folder is. Therefore the user has to pick the
>   folder."

So, attaching to a contaioner and then automatically opening a specific folder isn't possible, it seems. But I discovered that F1 *Remote-Containers: Reopen Folder in Container* roughly gets me where I want to go.

Answer (score 1):

`F1` **Remote-Containers: Open Named Container Configuration File**

```json
{
  "workspaceFolder": "/ado"
}
```

Then save, close the window and reattach it to the container.